# How to stop a build on a build agent with an HTTP command

Tags: teamcity

I need to stop a build on an agent with a script, then disable it.

I found in the forums a way to disable/enable agents :

```
http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/ajax.html?reason=&_should_restore_status=&status_restoring_delay=15&changeAgentStatus=<AGENT_ID>&enable=false&_=
http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/ajax.html?reason=&_should_restore_status=&status_restoring_delay=15&changeAgentStatus=<AGENT_ID>&enable=true&_=
```

Is there an http command to stop the running build on a particular agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be an [undocumented feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP?focusedCommentId=41485657#comment-41485657) for cancelling a build.  Support for this feature is by no means guaranteed. :)